# codeigniter not loading controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some trouble putting my webpage on production environment.

My config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcomePage";
```

It is a one & one server.
"http://www.mywebsite.com/" is linking to /web/. /web/ is the directory where my codeigniter app is instaled. It worked fine on localhost. Now, when I go to 'http://www.mywebsite.com/', I get a 404 not found error (the codeigniter one, so the "index.php" is at least loaded. Any idea? Thanks in advance! :)

EDDIT 1 ---------------------

.htacces:
    Deny from all

Comment: its 404 generated by browser or by codeigniter ?

Comment: show your `.htaccess`

Comment: it is generated by codeigniter :/

Comment: dianuj -> see my edit

Comment: I've just noticed that ther are loads of .htacces. Which one I have to mdofy or show? :S

Comment: okay, this works: mywebsite.com/index.php/welcomePage
but not the inicial scenario.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Should work...